# Filter Date From FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I want to filter my crop data table on the basis of dates. I uploaded my file in the assets and call it. Now I am unable to filter this data accordingly datewise.
The date column is added in the file but still, I am confused about how to filter. Please help!

```
var cropdate = shapefile.select('Column')
cropdate.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Date', '2017)).geometry();

var cropdate = shapefile.select('Column')
.filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
```

Comment: To allow others to reproduce your issue, you may want to share a script URL (obtained using the "Get Link" button) and share the data table (i.e. make it publicly accessible).

Comment: at least tell us whats the name of the `date` column of your table, and what's its format..